# Subgroup maximal in its normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, such that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $\operatorname{N}_G(H)$. Is there a sufficient condition for $H$ to be maximal in $\operatorname{N}_G(H)$?

What if $H$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, for some prime $p$? What if $H$ is furthermore of order $p$? What if $G$ is simple?

Comment: This is a somewhat trivial remark, but if $G$ is abelian then any $H \neq G$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer which is the entire group and so the maximal subgroups would be those of order $\frac{n}{p}$ for each prime $p$ dividing $n$.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple group ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$, a Sylow $3$-subgroup has order $3$, and its normalizer has order $12$, so it is not maximal in its normalizer.

Comment: Yes, I also know of counterexamples for some alternating groups of prime degree (such as $A_{13}$ with $p = 13$). I wasn't proposing $G$ simple or $H$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p$ as sufficient conditions, I was wondering if adding those helps in finding a sufficient condition